# nHibernate QueryOver get all records when parameter is null

Tags: c#, nhibernate, null

I have following situation. I have `Customer` and `CompanyCustomerAssignment` objects (with 1:1 relation). One of properties in `CompanyCustomerAssignment` is `CustomerGroup`.
Now - I would like to `QueryOver` - when `CustomerGroup` is passed, than fetch `Customers` which belongs to this group, but when it comes as null I would like to query all. Well it seems simple in "SQL":

```
...WHERE CustomerGroupId = @param OR @param is NULL;
```

Unfortunately I have no idea with QueryOver (`custGrp` is paramater - can be an object or `null`)

```
Customer c = null;
CompanyCustomerAssignment cca = null;

_session.QueryOver<Customer>(() => c)
    .JoinAlias(() => c.CompanyCustomerAssignment, () => cca)
    .Where(() => cca.Company == currentCompany && c.IsActive == true)
    .And(() => cca.CustomerGroup == custGrp || custGrp == null ) // <- this seems to be problem to me
    .List()
    .Select(x => new CustomerApiModel() {CustomerId = x.Id})
    .ToList();
```

But this does not work - I receive a message, that `Customer` does not have such a property, which sounds logical but does not help me at all.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In this case, we know the condition `@param is NULL` before the query is executed, or better before is assembled at all. So let's extend Criteria with `custGrp` only if it is filled.

```
var criteria = _session.QueryOver<Customer>(() => c)
    .JoinAlias(() => c.CompanyCustomerAssignment, () => cca)
    .Where(() => cca.Company == currentCompany && c.IsActive == true);

// if during the query build
if(custGrp != null)
{
  criteria.Where(() => cca.CustomerGroup == custGrp);
}

var results = criteria
    .List()
    ...
```

This makes the SQL part more efficient, and we can do more tricks...

Comment: Simplicity of your solution hides true genius behind. Thanks a lot - works like charm!